# Combining optional parameters and subqueries

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, postgis, parameterized-query

I'm writing a web service endpoint that lets you fetch `offices` from a PostgreSQL database. If an ID parameter is specified in the request, only the offices in a given `region` (matching that ID) should be returned; otherwise, *all* `offices` should be retrieved.

Below is the SQL query:

```
SELECT o.location
FROM (SELECT location FROM offices) AS o,
     (SELECT polygon FROM regions WHERE id = NULLIF($1, '')::int) AS r
WHERE (CASE WHEN $1 = '' THEN TRUE ELSE ST_Contains(r.polygon, o.location) END)
```

`$1` is the optional ID parameter, which defaults to an empty string if not provided in the request. [ST_Contains](http://postgis.org/docs/ST_Contains.html) is a PostGIS function.

The query works fine when `$1` is not an empty string. But when it *is* empty, no `offices` are fetched. :( For some reason, everything falls apart when the `r` sub-query does not return any rows.

What am I doing wrong?

It would be nice if I could simply ignore the `r` sub-query if `$1` is an empty string (i.e. make it an "optional sub-query", if you will).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT o.location
FROM (SELECT location FROM offices) AS o,
     (SELECT polygon FROM regions WHERE COALESCE(TRIM($1), '') = '' OR id = NULLIF($1,'')::INT) AS r
WHERE (CASE WHEN COALESCE(TRIM($1),'') = '' THEN TRUE ELSE ST_Contains(r.polygon, o.location) END)
```

Comment: I'm not following. How does `NULLIF($1, '') = ''` work?

Comment: When the $1 is not set then it will be NULL or ''. Then this condition will  be true. Otherwise it will check id = $1::INT. Changed the answer little bit.

Comment: But why `= ''`? It will never be true because `NULLIF` will return `NULL`.

Comment: Nope, still returns zero rows.